# Javascript " onsubmit " Event Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am just practicing js. I am trying to make a very simple validation in form but it came with, as i was expecting, an error. 
Here's my code :

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var email = document.getElementById('email');   
var msg = document.getElementById('message');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

function handlingForm() {

    form.onsubmit = function(c) 
    {
        if (name.value == "") 
            {
                error.innerHTML = "Error Submiting Form !";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                error.innerHTML = "You have successfuly submited the Form..! Congrats ;)";
                return true; // ;) Just Kidding :D
            }

    };
}   


window.onload = function(c)
{
    handlingForm();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsForm</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <form id="form">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
            <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send">
            <p id="error"></p>
        </form>

    </div>  

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, it doesn't validate it. Every time it returns true on submitting but when i replace the " name.value" with "email.value" the code works. I don't know now what's the problem actually. If someone could help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the input with id `name` is not created in DOM by the time of JavaScript execution. 
You can resolve that by putting the code in the `window.onload` code block or inside the `form.onsubmit`

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');

var email = document.getElementById('email');
var msg = document.getElementById('message');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

function handlingForm() {      
  form.onsubmit = function(c) {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    if (name.value == "") {
      error.innerHTML = "Error Submiting Form !";
      return false;
    } else {
      error.innerHTML = "You have successfuly submited the Form..! Congrats ;)";
      return true; // ;) Just Kidding :D
    }

  };
};
handlingForm();
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send">
    <p id="error"></p>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry.. wait I'll try

Comment: But can you explain it ?

Comment: Sure, the browser DOM at the time of JavaScript code execution was not build yet, which assigned 'undefined` for variable `name`. To make sure the input is created you need to execute that JavaScript code in `window.onload` DOM state or after that point in time.

Comment: Not quite. That doesn't explain why using `email` worked. By using `name` you are overriding the `this.name` value which is automatically set by javascript. If you rename your variable to `name_` it will work without having to relocate the line (see my answer below).

Comment: The script is linked from the end of the body, so all the elements happen to already exist when the script runs. What's key to it working is that `name` is now a local variable, entirely separate from `window.name`.

Comment: @deltab The behavior is unpredictable before the DOM is constructed. There may be some other initialization code that get in the way (like window.name for window title).

Answer (score 1):

Your variable called `name` is a problem.  It's not working because `name` is a predefined identifier in some implementations.  Though it's not a reserved keyword, it's best practice to avoid using it as a variable name.

Rename it to `name_` (or almost anything else) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If `name.value` has no value, it is `undefined`. So `undefined !== ""`, which is why it will never be true. Just do a null check for `name.value`. Also, you need to move `name` inside of that function since the first time it is called, `value` will always be undefined:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var email = document.getElementById('email');   
var msg = document.getElementById('message');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

function handlingForm() {

    form.onsubmit = function(c) 
    {
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        if (!name.value) 
            {
                error.innerHTML = "Error Submiting Form !";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                error.innerHTML = "You have successfuly submited the Form..! Congrats ;)";
                return true; // ;) Just Kidding :D
            }

    };
}   


window.onload = function(c)
{
    handlingForm();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsForm</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <form id="form">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
            <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send">
            <p id="error"></p>
        </form>

    </div>  

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed that! Moved `name` inside the `onsubmit` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = handlingForm();
```

Why your function has `c` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a quirk of how global variables are handled in web pages. Each one is treated as a property of the `window` object, so when you assign to `email`, you're actually creating and assigning to `window.email`, and so on.

However, some properties of the window object already exist and have special meaning to the browser, such as `window.location` (the current URL) and `window.name` (used in cross-frame link targets).

To see it in practice, do this in the global scope (outside any function):

```
var location;     // should be undefined, right?
alert(location);  // but it's actually window.location
```

Because of the special meaning of `window.name`, anything you assign to it (or to global `name`) will be converted into a string. The element that you try to store becomes a string, and so no longer works as an element.

**To fix it, simply move your code into a function, so that the variables are local** and no longer have this strange behaviour. You can use your `window.onload` function for this.